# Azure Maps Fuzzy Search API (https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/fuzzy/json?) works on Postman but fails on Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-maps

I started using the Azure Maps API on a project using Logic Apps (Azure). All of a sudden the HTTP action stopped working and I am getting a 400 BadRequest Error.

"error": {
    "code": "400 BadRequest",
    "message": "Bad request: one or more parameters were incorrectly specified or are mutually exclusive."

However, when I call the same API using Postman or my browser, it works fine.

API: https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/fuzzy/json?api-version=1.0&subscription-key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&query=2 5 Donlands Ave 4 Toronto Toronto   &countrySet=Ca&maxFuzzyLevel=2&limit=1

As I mentioned, this was working and all of a sudden started failing on Logic Apps without making any changes.

Comment: Hi, could you please share some more details(such as screenshots) about how did you request the api in logic app ?

Comment: Thanks @HuryShen - I am using the built-in HTTP action. I checked the Raw input and it's identical to what it used to be when it was working. The one difference I notice between the last time this worked 5 days ago, is that the output headers contained:  "Vary": "Accept-Encoding" backed when it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I exactly have the same issue.
I use address rest api to retrieve cities from postal code.

Sample :

https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/address/structured/json?subscription-key=mySubcriptionKey&api-version=1.0&postalcode=35000&countrycode=fr&limit=1

Like you, if I use the query client side, I have a 400 bad request with message :
{
  "error": {
    "code": "400 BadRequest",
    "message": "Bad request: one or more parameters were incorrectly specified or are mutually exclusive."
  }
}

Please note that the query is OK for google chrome, but return a 400 bad requests with Brave, Edge (chromium) and Firefox.
Note also that the sample web sdk have the same issue and is not updated.

Currently, I don't have any idea about where is the problem.

Edit : After some investigation, i'm pretty sure that it's a Microsoft issue.
So, I found a workaround.
If I try my query with Firefox, by default I have a 400 and a 200 with chrome.
I compare the header and the issue is with the accept-language.

By default, on Chrome, I Have : Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
On Firefox (Brave, Edge also maybe), I Have : Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3

Please note the inversion between fr-FR and fr.
If I change my Accept-Language on Firefox from fr,fr-FR to FR-fr,fr. It's working.

If I set my Accept-Language to "fr" only, I still have a 400. Work with "Fr-fr".
So after some test, my conclusion is that atlas have an issue with two letter header accept-langage.

So on my TS/JS code, just add accept-language with 4 letters to work again.

```
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept-Language", this.acceptLanguage);
xhr.send();
```

My opinion is that it's a server/ atlas issue, I can't imagine this kind of code evolution from Microsoft ^^

Comment: Thanks @MathieuMN - Since I am using Logic Apps (on Azure) I don't think I am able to make these changes. I confirm that when I send the request via Internet Explorer it fails (Bad Request/400), however it works on my Edge browser and on Postman.

Comment: Effectively, it's not easy. I currently don't know how work Logic Apps but I suppose that you have to send your query somewhere ? Do you have the capacity to add additional parameters ? Like a curl request or http request ? Something like :  -H "accept-language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7" ^

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did. I tried re-answering my original question but I'll put it here. I had to add a header as you suggested: accept-language en-US . This header wasn't previously required and after I added the API worked fine.