# Error parsing accept-language header in "search/fuzzy/json" api

Tags: azure-maps, http-accept-language

We've come across a strange issue with fuzzy search requests that have begun to start failing in some browsers.

Running the search from test page [here](https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/Services%20Module/Fuzzy%20Search%20using%20Services%20Module.html) works. If you view this request in the network tab, and copy it as CURL, you get something like:

```
curl 'https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/fuzzy/json?api-version=1.0&query=New%20York&radius=100000&view=Auto&subscription-key=tTk1JVEaeNvDkxxnxHm9cYaCvqlOq1u-fXTvyXn2XkA' \
  -H 'authority: atlas.microsoft.com' \
  -H 'dnt: 1' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'ms-am-request-origin: ServiceModule' \
  -H 'map-agent: ServiceModule/2.0.5 (Web)' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'origin: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: cross-site' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'referer: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/Services%20Module/Fuzzy%20Search%20using%20Services%20Module.html' \
  --compressed
```

If you right click on the search request and click "open in new tab", it fails with 400/Bad Request. If you copy this request as CURL, it will give you something like:

```
curl 'https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/fuzzy/json?api-version=1.0&query=New%20York&radius=100000&view=Auto&subscription-key=tTk1JVEaeNvDkxxnxHm9cYaCvqlOq1u-fXTvyXn2XkA' \
  -H 'authority: atlas.microsoft.com' \
  -H 'cache-control: max-age=0' \
  -H 'dnt: 1' \
  -H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: none' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: navigate' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-user: ?1' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: document' \
  -H 'accept-language: en,nl;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8' \
  --compressed
```

which will fail. I've narrowed down the problem to the accept-language param 'en,nl;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8' which Chrome seems to have added as a default when I opened in the GET request in the new tab. Replacing this val with 'en-US' makes the request work again.

I've reproduced this on:
Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, Chrome Version 81.0.4044.129 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Windows Version 10.0.18362 Build 18362, Chrome Version 81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) (64-bit)
and we've also had customers report it on Edge and Chrome.

So, assuming this default value for accept-language is valid, it seems there's a bug in the azure api parsing it.

A workaround for this problem is to chrome://settings/?search=language and set just one language.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that an invalid language parameter is being passed in. A list of supported languages can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/supported-languages Passing anything other than one of these would result in an error. To address this issue, you can either override the accept-language header, or add a language parameter to the request "&language=en-US".

Comment: Thanks Ricky. I belive the value string is valid and both languages are listed as supported in that link (en, nl). Was there a change made recently to this? It seems that "en,nl;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8" should be parseable and the intention clear.

Re. anything other than one of the supported accept-language values causing a 400/Bad Request: that seems unusual. I'd have thought it's more conventional (and useful) to ignore the header in that case, or as suggested [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language) possibly return a 406/Not Acceptable.

Comment: I'll pass it along to the dev team. But as it is today, the accept-language has to be exactly one of the ones listed and nothing more/less.

Comment: Thank you. Just to give some further context to the issue: if the intended clients of this API were programmatic (Java etc), it wouldn't be much of an issue but as it's a JS API, intended for usage from a browser, it's very fragile for people outside of the US. Go to: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/REST%20Services/Search%20Autosuggest%20and%20JQuery%20UI.html In Chrome lang settings, set preferred language as English or French e.g. https://imgur.com/a/ebpef6b and try the sample page again and it will fail. This is what some of our users are seeing.

Comment: Hi Ricky, some further info: we're seeing this on the map tiles API now too i.e. some users (depending on locale) aren't seeing a map anymore. Again, this isn't just on our app but on Azure Map sample pages e.g. https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/Controls/Map%20Navigation%20Control%20Options.html

Comment: I've escalated this to our engineering team for investigation.

Comment: Looks like the team has already been working on part of this. In a couple of days the language parameter will override the accept-language header and should provide one option to move forward. A larger solution is planned for language support in general for later this year which would provide better support for accept-language values.

Comment: Thanks Ricky. We'll probably go with setting the accept-language header.

For other viewers reference, this issue is also logged:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/93202bc3-d8b9-402f-a33c-1951788fbbcd/calls-to-fuzzy-search-fail-depending-on-browser-language?forum=azurelbs

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/909172-azure-maps/suggestions/40488322-accept-language-set-to-2-letter-culture-returns-40

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61829909/azure-maps-fuzzy-search-api-https-atlas-microsoft-com-search-fuzzy-json-wor